# Table Join Referencing Same Primary Key T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

Is it valid to have a `Table` which references the same `Primary Key` to assign a value to multiple of it's `Foreign Key`? I.E. :

Table Menu

```
ItemID(PK)  DishName        Category
  1         Fried Chicken   Poultry
  2         Salmon          Fish
  3         Spaghetti       Pasta
  4         Steak           Beef
  5         Roasted Cod     Fish
  6         Baked Halibut   Fish
  7         Maple Duck      Poultry
```

Table `[TableOrder]` where `OrderItem#` refers to the primary key of the `Menu` table.

```
PartyID OrderItem1(FK)  OrderItem2(FK)  OrderItem3(FK)
    1       3               2               5
    2       7               1               2
    3       2               5               6
    4       4               4               2
    5       6               3               2
```

Is it possible (how could you) to return a `query` that lists the category as such? (Where `Order#Cat` is an `alias` to `Category` in the `Menu` table using an (Inner) `Join`)

```
PartyID Order1Cat  Order2Cat  Order3Cat
  1     Pasta       Fish        Fish    
  2     Poultry     Poultry     Fish    
  3     Fish        Fish        Fish    
  4     Beef        Beef        Fish    
  5     Fish        Pasta       Fish
```

As in

```
 SELECT        
     [Table Order].PartyID, [Table Order].OrderItem1, 
     [TableOrder].OrderItem2, [Table Order].OrderItem3, 
     Menu.Category
 FROM
     [Table Order] 
 INNER JOIN
     Menu ON [Table Order].OrderItem1 = Menu.ItemID
     ...
     (alias ?)...
     (subquery ?)...
```

If not, please suggest an alternative structure that would permit similiar results. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's almost always a better design to have separate *rows* so that all data of the same type ends up in the *same* column - this makes querying easier, you can still have an additional column *if* the numbers `1`, `2` and `3` are actually relevant, you're not artificially limited to only have three items in the order (and forced to store nulls when there are less than 3), etc.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for the response. I am not sure I follow on "rows". Are you referring to such as in `[TableOrder]` instead of a numerical `1`-`5` value passing a `check` for `Fish`, `Beef`, etc ? The numbers are not inherently relevant, so much as they would allow the returning of (At least I believe with my experience) of say the `DishName` value as opposed to `Category` as an option. Or are you referring to if there was a `Order4Cat` column; in the case I would have to pass an `alter` statement to the table?

Comment: Yes, it would be better if `TableOrder` had columns `PartyID` and `ItemID` and then, say, three rows for party 1 - `1,3`, `1,2` and `1,5` (and similar rows for the other parties). It will make more general queries ("find every party who ordered items 2 and 4") far easier to write in the future.

Comment: Additional `ItemID` columns for a party that orders more than 1 item? The second being `ItemID2`? Say party 1 orders 1 item, and party 8 orders 10; I would have (at the time of party 8's entry 7 more columns than at party 1? If updated those 7 columns would be null for party 1 (not a problem) ?

Comment: No, add more *rows* - so you store 1 row for a party that orders 1 item and 10 rows for a party that orders 10. You don't want to have to keep changing the table definition if the maximum number of items included in an order changes. You *might* want one extra column that stored `1` for the first item ordered, `2` for the second item ordered, etc, if that ordering is important - currently you're embedding that *data* into column names - which makes it doubly difficult to write decent queries.

Comment: Thanks for advice. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
SELECT tblo.PartyID, 
       tm1.Category Order1Cat,
       tm2.Category Order2Cat,
       tm3.Category Order3Cat
FROM [Table Order] tblo
INNER JOIN [Table Menu] tm1
    ON tblo.OrderItem1 = tm1.ItemID
INNER JOIN [Table Menu] tm2
    ON tblo.OrderItem2 = tm2.ItemID
INNER JOIN [Table Menu] tm3
    ON tblo.OrderItem3 = tm3.ItemID
```

Comment: This was successful, thank you. Albeit, I removed all `to.` references (To compile). Could you explain it so I can accept? I have never seen it done like this. Is `to` meant to be `[Table Order]`?

Comment: in the query above, i use `to` as an alias for `[Table Order]` but it's also a [reserve keywork](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in sql-server. So, it explains why you have to change the alias, for example `tblo` to avoid syntax error.

Comment: I figured, was confused if you were using `to` to accomplish something. As I said it appears not to be required (at least in this case), but is likely best practice. Thanks again for your help.